# Getting POSTed data in a Clojure / Ring / HttpKit application

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, http-kit, clojure-ring

I'm writing a simple HttpKit / Ring application and am trying to post some data from a form to it.

Here's the relevant part of my server code :

```
(defn save-page [request]
  (let [qs (:query-string request)
        fp (:form-params request)]
    (println "SAVE PAGE :: ")
    (println (str request))
    (println (str "CCCC" fp))
    (println (str qs))))

(defn handler [{:keys [uri request-method] :as request}]
  (let []
    (cond 
      ; view a page 
      (= uri "/clj_ts/view")
      (get-page request)

      (= uri "/clj_ts/save")
      (save-page request)

      :otherwise 

      .. STUFF )))

(defn -main [& args]
  (-> #'handler
      (wrap-content-type)
      (wrap-keyword-params)
      (wrap-params)
      (wrap-reload)
      (wrap-resource "clj_ts")
      (run-server {:port 0})))
```

Here's the client-side code which posts to it.

```
(defn generate-form-data [params]
  (let [form-data (js/FormData.)]
    (doseq [[k v] params]
      (.append form-data (name k) v))
    form-data))

(defn save-page! []
  (let [page-name (-> @db :current-page)
        new-data (-> js/document
                     (.getElementById "edit-field") 
                     .-value)
        form-data (generate-form-data 
                    {"page" page-name
                     "data" new-data})] 
    (js/console.log "SAVING")
    (js/console.log (str new-data))
    (.send XhrIo
      "/clj_ts/save"
      (fn [e] e)
      "POST"
      form-data)))
```

Now I can see from my browser's developer tools that I am POSTing up something with form-data that contains values for page and data.

But in my server-side code, the :form-params of the request is empty.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I always [use the library `cljs-ajax`](https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax) instead of direct JS interop.  Then you can do something like:

```
; Post a transit format message
(POST "/send-message"
        {:params {:message "Hello World"
                  :user    "Bob"}
         :handler handler
         :error-handler error-handler})
```

They also have explicit FormData support:

```
; Send file explicitly, ClojureScript specific
(let [form-data (doto
                    (js/FormData.)
                  (.append "id" "10")
                  (.append "file" js-file-value "filename.txt"))]
  (POST "/send-file" {:body form-data
                      :response-format (raw-response-format)
                      :timeout 100}))
```

Their README is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, because of reasons, I can't really use cljs-axaj ... Also, it doesn't seem like the problem is the client side. The browser looks like its posting the right thing up to the server. It's that I'm not receiving it there.